# how to commit changes on gremlin server using gremlin python

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I am writing a script to create a graph on gremlin-server using the gremlin-python library. I could not find any good documentation for the library.

This is the code structure with which I am experimenting:

```
from    gremlin_python                                  import statics
from    gremlin_python.structure.graph                  import Graph
from    gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal          import __
from    gremlin_python.process.strategies               import *
from    gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection  import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()

g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','try1'))

# Drop all vertices in the graph to create a new one
g.V().drop().iterate()

a = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me')
b = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Avi').property('pronoun','you')

e1 = a.addE('knows').to(b).property('relation','self')

c = g.addV('subject').property('name','maths')

e2 = a.addE('studies').to(c)

e3 = b.addE('studies').to(c)
e3.next()

v = g.V().toList()
e = g.E().toList()

print(v)
print(e)
```

This code gives me only 2 vertices, and 1 edge.

Some of my tries :

- When I try the code without `.next()`, no data gets committed on the graph.
- When I give `e1` a `.next()`, 2 different vertices and 1 different edge gets created
- When I add `.next()` to `e2` and `e1`, an error is thrown saying `StopIteration`
- When I add `.next()` to `e3` and `e1`, I get 4 vertices and 2 edges

My graph should have 3 vertices and 3 nodes. And what I really want is to commit changes made by the script on the graph.

Some additional information :

- I am storing the graph in graphson format
- I am using Python3.6

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to [iterate your traversals](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration). In other words, when you make this kind of assignment:

```
a = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me')
```

nothing gets sent to the server and "a" does not contain your new vertex. You've simply assigned a `Traversal` instance to "a" - see this demonstrated in the following in Groovy:

```
gremlin> t = g.addV('person').property('name','tushar').property('pronoun','me');[]
gremlin> t.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal
gremlin> a = t.next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> a.class
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex
```

So, that leads to the next isssue. You are thinking "a" is a `Vertex` object for which you want to call `addE()` on, but we've already established that "a" is in fact a `Traversal`. In the first place, `Vertex` does not have an `addE()` method so even if that was a `Vertex` this approach would not work. Second, because you have a `Traversal` object which does have an `addE()` method, you're ending up with this situation demonstrated in Groovy:

```
gremlin> a = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me');[]
gremlin> b = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Avi').property('pronoun','you');[]
gremlin> 
gremlin> e1 = a.addE('knows').to(b).property('relation','self');[]
gremlin> e1.toString()
==>[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[me], label=[person], name=[Tushar]}), AddEdgeStep({label=[knows], ~to=[[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[you], label=[person], name=[Avi]})]], relation=[self]})]
gremlin> 
gremlin> c = g.addV('subject').property('name','maths');[]
gremlin> 
gremlin> e2 = a.addE('studies').to(c);[]
gremlin> e2.toString()
==>[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[me], label=[person], name=[Tushar]}), AddEdgeStep({label=[knows], ~to=[[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[you], label=[person], name=[Avi]})]], relation=[self]}), AddEdgeStep({label=[studies], ~to=[[AddVertexStartStep({label=[subject], name=[maths]})]]})]
gremlin> 
gremlin> e3 = b.addE('studies').to(c);[]
gremlin> e3.toString()
==>[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[you], label=[person], name=[Avi]}), AddEdgeStep({label=[studies], ~to=[[AddVertexStartStep({label=[subject], name=[maths]})]]})]
gremlin> e3.next()
==>e[8][3-studies->6]
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[8][3-studies->6]
```

Note the lines where I did a `toString()`. Again, you don't have a result there as you expect, but instead a `Traversal`. In each of those `toString()`'d traversals you can see that you've really just built a more complex traversal, embedding one within the other. Taking the first one in more detail:

```
gremlin> a = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me');[]
gremlin> b = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Avi').property('pronoun','you');[]
gremlin> e1 = a.addE('knows').to(b).property('relation','self');[]
gremlin> e1.toString()
==>[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[me], label=[person], name=[Tushar]}), AddEdgeStep({label=[knows], ~to=[[AddVertexStartStep({pronoun=[you], label=[person], name=[Avi]})]], relation=[self]})]
```

So, with those lines of code you basically constructed the traversal:

```
g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me').
  addE('knows').to(addV('person').
                   property('name', 'Avi').
                   property('pronoun','you')).property('relation','self')
```

Then "e1" is never iterated so that data never gets added. Your code should be altered as follows for it to work:

```
from    gremlin_python                                  import statics
from    gremlin_python.structure.graph                  import Graph
from    gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal          import __
from    gremlin_python.process.strategies               import *
from    gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection  import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()

g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','try1'))

# Drop all vertices in the graph to create a new one
g.V().drop().iterate()

a = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me').next()
b = g.addV('person').property('name', 'Avi').property('pronoun','you').next()
g.addE('knows').from_(a).to(b).property('relation','self').iterate()

c = g.addV('subject').property('name','maths').next()

e2 = g.addE('studies').from_(a).to(c).next()

e3 = g.addE('studies').from_(b).to(c).next()

v = g.V().toList()
e = g.E().toList()

print(v)
print(e)
```

I believe the above syntax however will only work on the latest version of TinkerPop. Personally I would prefer if the above to be just written as:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name', 'Tushar').property('pronoun', 'me').as('a').
......1>   addV('person').property('name', 'Avi').property('pronoun','you').as('b').
......2>   addV('subject').property('name','maths').as('c').
......3>   addE('knows').from_('a').to('b').property('relation','self').
......4>   addE('studies').from_('a').to('c').
......5>   addE('studies').from_('a').to('c').iterate()
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[23][15-knows->18]
==>e[24][15-studies->21]
==>e[25][15-studies->21]
```

In this way, your traversal gets sent to the server once and generates all the data in a single request.

Finally, regarding:

> I could not find any good documentation for the library.

You will note that I demonstrated your code in the Gremlin Console, which is Groovy based. It is a cut/paste fit. In that way, any documentation on Gremlin, and there is a lot, will be helpful to you. Please don't get distracted by the fact that the examples you come across are mostly in Groovy. The only differences are language specific syntax (e.g. Java doesn't have single quotes to represents strings, Python has a few steps that conflict with reserved words in Python so they have a underscore pinned to the end like `not_`). Basically, Gremlin is Gremlin in whatever language you choose to use - just learn the subtle difference in syntax and it should get easier. All that said, we hope to translate more of our documentation to have language specific syntax - you can watch this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/766) if you are interested in following that.

Comment: When the requests are sent in multiple statement/line, its not rolling back. Any solution?

Comment: it depends - if you're talking about the Gremlin Console and you are using a `:remote` then you need to use the "session" flag: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-sessions if you are talking about Gremlin code in your application then you need to submit scripts using a session with a graph that supports transactions - see the "Submitting Scripts" section for the programming language you are using here https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference

Comment: finally, for 3.5.0 there are remote transactions for java with bytecode https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/upgrade/#_transaction_improvements - other programming languages will also support this model in future releases along the 3.5.x line

Comment: Thank you @stephen mallette, I was looking Gremlin code in application. Thanks for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: @stephenmallette this is simply a fantastic answer.  I'd upvote 100 times if possible.